# How to replace a string conditionally in Python?

Tags: python

I need to look for a substring in a string and if I don't find it, perform an action. So I do this, and it works fine:

```
if 'AAA' not in myString: 
   print "AAA is not in myString"
```

What I need, however, is to avoid cases where AAA is a part of XAAA. In other words, I don't want my script to notice any presence of "XAAA" when it does  `if 'AAA' not in myString`. So how can I modify the above if-clause to the following:

```
if 'AAA' not in myString except for cases where 'AAA' is a part of 'XAAA':
    print "AAA is not in myString"
```

Comment: `if 'AAA' not in myString.replace('XAAA', ''):`?

Comment: I'd suggest renaming this question.  Something like "How to replace a string conditionally in Python"

Comment: @AdamHughes Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want my script to notice any presence of `"XAAA"` when it does  `if 'AAA' not in myString`.

You can first remove any occurrences of the sub-string `XAAA` from `myString`, and *then* test if `AAA` is not a sub-string of `myString`:

```
if 'AAA' not in myString.replace('XAAA', ''):
    # do action
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works with `XAAAA` or `AAXAAAA`. The question was unclear about this case.

Answer (score 8):

I like re module solutions

```
if not re.search(r'(?<!X)AAA', myString):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways.

You can remove `XAAA` from the string then compare:

```
if 'AAA' not in myString.replace('XAAA', ''):
    # do something
```

Or you can check for it first then compare:

```
if 'XAAA' not in myString:
    if 'AAA' not in myString:
        # do something
```

Two-liner:

```
if 'XAAA' not in myString and 'AAA' not in myString:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regular expressions** might serve you extremely-well here.

For instance, you could match the string against the so-called "regex," **`/[^X]?AAA/`**.

This regex tests for the existence of any string `AAA` which is *not* preceded by the character `X`, anywhere in the string.

(The `?` is needed to support the possibility that the `AAA` occurs at the beginning of the string, where no `X` could possibly precede it.)

*Every* programming language supports regular expressions ... "and this is why."

(FYI: *"regular expressions are an immensely-deep pool of water, that it is very well worth exploring."* In practical application, it produces many "practical applications," such as this one, even if all that you ever do is to skim the surface of it and very-happily stay there.)

Comment: (This answer, by the way, has been tested ...)

Comment: Didn't Gribouillis use regex in his answer though?